# is it good practice to have a text over a symbol which contains both super- and subscript?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

My problem involves the Greek letter `$\Psi$` which is a sum of two parts - a volumetric (vol) part and a deviatoric (part). I have to associate a superscript `$h$` and optionally a subscript `$a$` to `$\psi$`, that is, there is no place to store `$\text{vol}$` in a sub- or superscript.
Thus, my idea was to write `$\text{vol}$` over `$\Psi$`.

Is it a good practice to do it like this or is it reasonable to write `$\text{vol}$` as a left sub- or superscript?

Anyway, the output of the MWE does not look nice because the superscript `$h$` starts above `$\text{vol}$`. I would like to have the superscript next to `$\psi$` such that it looks like `$\psi^h$`.

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Vol}[2][]{% first argument #1 optional
        \ifstrempty{#1}%
            {%
                \overset{\text{vol}}{#2}%
            }{%
                \overset{\text{vol}}{#2}^{#1}%
            }%
}

$\Vol{\psi}^h$ does not like nice...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `$\text{vol}$` is wrong in all circumstanses. `\text` does not do what you think. Try `\textit{$\text{vol}$}`, if it is just ascii, use `\mathrm` instead,

Comment: I think it will confuse the reader if you write it on top. Might be better to see what is tradition in your field. On can easily use `\Psi_{h,\mahrm{vol}}`

Comment: The superscript h is only sometimes associated with psi (like the subscript), that is, can your suggestion Psi_{h,\mahrm{vol}} be encoded in a newcommand?